# Waiting on Nomad server

Tags: nomad

I am currently trying to build some integrations tests with Nomad.

For that I try:

```
nomad agent -dev -config=test.conf&
nomad run test.nomad
```

which of course fails, since it tries to submit the job before the server is running.
The bad option would be to insert a sleep.
My question is, whether there is a better way to wait until the server is up and accepts jobs.

Answer (score 1):

So a only halfway hacky solution is:

```
wait_for_agent() {
  while test -z $(curl -s http://127.0.0.1:4646/v1/agent/health)
  do
    sleep 1
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another hack :-)

```
nomad agent -dev -config=test.conf && nomad run test.nomad
```